# Can Part 141 instrument simulated time be logged?

Tags: faa-regulations

I'm doing my IR rating in Part 141, and the school says you cannot log simulated time in the logbook, whereas in Part 61 they are allowed. Why?

Comment: Do you mean _simulator_ (i.e. approved flight simulator device) time or _simulated_ (i.e. hood) time? If they say you cant log _simulated_  (hood) time go find another school... If you cant log simulator time, thats up to you. It basically means you have to do all your training in an actual aircraft, might be more pricy but not necessarily a bad thing.

Answer (score 3):

The FAA's [Advisory Circular 61-136B](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_61-136B.pdf) addresses this subject and explains how time on an advanced training device should be logged:

> D.3 Logging Training Time and Experience.
>
> Authorized instructors
> utilizing an FAA-approved ATD for airmen training, pilot time, and
> experience requirements are required to log the time as dual
> instruction and as basic aviation training device (BATD) or advanced
> aviation training device (AATD) time appropriately. Any columns that
> reference flight time should remain blank when logging ATD time. ATD
> time can only be logged as Instruction Received (Dual), Instrument
> Time, or Total Time as reflected on the pilot time section of FAA Form
> 8710-1, Airman Certificate and/or Rating Application. Simulated
> instrument time can be logged in an ATD, but only during the time when
> the visual component of the training session is configured for
> instrument meteorological conditions (IMC) and the pilot is
> maintaining control solely by reference to the flight instruments.
> Logging time in this fashion will allow a pilot to credit this time
> towards the aeronautical experience and instrument experience
> requirements as specified in part 61 or part 141. It is required under
> § 61.51(b)(1)(iv) that the type and identification of the ATD be
> included when logging pilot time as described in the letter of
> authorization (LOA). It is the responsibility of the flight
> instructor, student, or certificated pilot to verify the device is
> qualified and approved for training or experience requirements. It
> would be appropriate for the person using the ATD to retain a copy of
> the LOA. Evaluators such as Designated Pilot Examiners (DPE) are
> instructed to request a copy of the LOA from applicants logging ATD
> pilot time, to verify the time acquired in the trainer qualifies for
> the minimum experience requirements for a certificate or rating.
>
> Note: There are no restrictions on the amount of training accomplished and
> logged in training devices. However, the regulatory limitations on
> maximum credit allowed for the minimum pilot certification
> requirements are specified by parts 61 and 141 and in the LOA. No
> approvals or authorizations are provided for aircraft type ratings
> using ATDs.

Answer (score 2):

You can log any simulated instrument time with a view limiting device in an aircraft with a legal safety pilot.
You can log simulated instrument time in an aviation training device or simulator when it is:

1. Approved for training (stated in a letter of authorization [LOA] for
   the specific unit.)
2. It is configured for flight solely by reference to instruments. (set to full IMC conditions/gray screen)
3. And you log both the model and registration or serial number(found in the LOA) in place of aircraft model and registration. ie Redbird FMX 0071

This logging is parallel to 141 course minimums. In other words you may or may not be able to count a specific flight toward 141 requirements but you can always count it toward your personal totals for part 61 currency, insurance, and job application purposes. For example you may enroll in a 141 instrument course and at some point use a CFI as a safety pilot to practice some simulated instrument under VFR, you can log this toward personal simulated instrument totals but it would not count toward the 35 hour minimum of 141 "instruction" because that requires a CFII.

Now I have heard a persistent incorrect statement from some instructors that claims "Conditions of flight" is only actual flight in a real aircraft, so they do not log simulated instrument time from a ground trainer in that column. Instead they rename some other misc column or use some other kludge. I feel that this practice is not aligned with **title 14 CFR part 61.51 (b)(3)iii** which explicitly states that logging the condition of flight includes simulated instrument time in full simulators, FTDs, and aviation training devices.

I always recommend including the specific syllabus lesson[s] as a log note if the flight was part of 141 training.

Comment: Now the real tricky questions are what is meant by instrument training in part 141 as this is different phrasing than part 61 instrument training. part 61 requires 40 hours flight by reference to the instruments, 141 requires 35 hours of instrument training. To me this implies that its 35 total time, not all on instruments, but that time is approved 141 curriculum.

Comment: The second question is if you are a commercial student and use your CFI for a safety pilot for a few minutes during a commercial lesson to stay up on instrument skills how is that logged? It doesn't count as an instrument lesson because they are not a CFII, but is it dual received as part of a commercial lesson and they are a valid safety pilot for logging sim instr time. For example when traveling to and from the maneuver practice area or en route on a cross country flght.